# Receiving two subscriptions emails when run cron using rules

Tags: rules, notifications

I need to send subscriptions immediately to users upon updating content. It is sending one subscriptions email when I run cron manually. But, when I run cron using rules, it send two subscriptions emails.

I have checked and found that I get one email only when I use rule to send test email.

Subscriptions setting: Users are not subscribed to content type...they are subscribed to taxonomy terms only.

Using modules for mail setup:
1. Mail system.
2. Mimemail.
3. Subscriptions.
4. Mail templates.

How can I send one subscriptions email only to each users upon updating content?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this. I noticed that it was rules who was getting trigger two times. This  [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1704290)  help me.  I thetrigger me to disable another rule on same event condition.